# jQuery validate success message shows on click of each element but when I submit the page and then go back success message is gone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form in place that shows a `.questionTitle__valid` class when we validate each element on the page.

Here is my code

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (e) {
        $(e).closest('.questionWrap').addClass('error');
        $(e).closest('.questionWrap').find('.questionTitle').removeClass('questionTitle__valid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (e) {
        var qWrap = $(e).closest('.questionWrap');
        $(e).closest('.questionWrap').find('.questionTitle').addClass('questionTitle__valid');
        if (qWrap.find('.field-validation-error').length == 0) {
            $(e).closest('.questionWrap').removeClass("error");   
        }
    },
    onclick: function (e) {
        this.element(e);
    },
    ignore: ':hidden:not(.validateHidden)'
});
```

My issue is when I submit the page and go to page 2 and then go back to page 1 the `.questionTitle__valid` has disappeared.

I thought if I called this on document.ready

`$('.pet_questions:visible').find(":input").valid();`

Which validates is visible element, but on first load of the page the validate plugin is run and shows all the error messages.

Its like I need to call validate if all elements have been filled out filled out like this

```
$('.pet_questions:visible').find(":input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $(this).valid();
    }
});
```

But if I add this the error messages still loads on first page load

Any help would be greatly appreciated to call jQuery validate if all elements have already been filled out on document.ready

Comment: I'm thinking i need to figure out how to bind the form on submit so when I refresh the page the `questionTitle__valid` class is still present.

Comment: Hitting the back button is a problem because certain page handlers are not fired again.

Comment: Why are you allowing the user to "go back" in the first place?  Once submitted, it's done.

Comment: Its a quote form. First page is Pet details. Second Page is customer details. So users may need to go back and edit their pet details

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort this, so when the user goes back to a page, I revalidate the form if the first question has already been answered and only validate the fields that are visible. This might not be a pretty way to do this but seems to work for me.

```js
if ($(".petspecieradio:checked").length > 0) {
    $('.pet_questions:visible').find(":input").valid();
}
```